# Porque quando instalo o Axios na minha aplicação next não consigo rodar ela?

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js

Estou aprendendo NextJs e queria criar um projeto com Next e Axios mas sempre que eu instalo o axios a aplicação para de funcionar. Obs: esse projeto também tem TypeScript e Styled-Components

**Comandos:**

```
1 - npx create-next-app app --example with-typescript-styled-components
2 - cd app
3 - npm install axios
4- npm run dev
```

**Erro**

```
'next' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! with-typescript-styled-components@1.0.0 dev: `next`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the with-typescript-styled-components@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\diego\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-07T19_28_05_002Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "with-typescript-styled-components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "15.0.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.9",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

após muitos tempo eu descobri que o problema era meu computador, ele era muito fraco então alguns pacotes erram corrompidos na hora da instalação

Comment: Precisaríamos de mais informações para ajudar, poderia compartilhar seu `package.json` e o que o projeto mostrar quando você não tem o Axios instalado?

Comment: eu não consigo rodar ele localmente. Ainda mostra apenas tela padrão do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está no seu `package.json`, o script `dev` está como:

```js
{
  "dev": "next"
}
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
{
  "dev": "next dev"
}
```

Comment: Tentei mas ainda continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Criei uma PR lá, vê se o da branch vai rodar